# Checkout issue in tfs

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs

i  have added a workspace(c:/users/aparna/workspace)and checked out the codes there. Due a mapping issue i changed the workspace, that is i created a new one (d:/noscript). When i tried to check out the project modules to this new workspcae from tfs, it is already mapped to the old workspace. When i open new workspace folde, .metadata and remotesystemTempFiles are seen. Projects modules still resides in old workspace. When i open eclipse by selecting new workspace, i got all project modules resides in old workspace.. what is the reason for this? Will it make any performance issue?

Comment: performance issues are there none, but inconsistencies as you have 2 different sources...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TFS, one workspace does **not** allow **the same TFS folder to be mapped to more than one local directory.**

However, you can have two or more workspaces for one computer, and each workspace can map a TFS folder to a different local folder. Seems your project modules already mapped with the old workspace.

This will not cause any performance issue. But what revisions of files are in each workspace is tracked separately (to keep each up to date you need to do a get in each) One easy  way is using  `tf get` from the command line.

If you don't want to track files separately in two workspaces, you could remove the mapping with old workspace for all the project modules. Select the old worksapce, go to **Team Explorer-> Source Control** - Right click on folder/project you've got before - Select **Remove Mapping**

Then you could remap and get latest in the new workspace.