# Why the users are still able to checkout the same file even it's been disabled?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015

In visual studio, team explorer> project settings> source control I have disabled the Multiple Check-outs and also enforced check-in policy for a project. Also, I have changed the workspace to server version but still, the programmers of the projects are able to checkout at a time. why?

Comment: "In visual studio, team explorer> project settings> source control I have disabled the Multiple Check-outs and also enforced check-in policy for a project." - **why?!** - that's awful for your users. If you're having problems with merging branches there are much better alternatives (for one thing: switching to `git`).

Comment: @Dai as of now this is the requirement from the management and yes i agree with you but I have to what has been told to do.

Comment: it's been awhile since I've worked with tfs (plauged with issues like you're experiencing). 
 this answer may be relevant in regards to workspaces and keeping up to date. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47151070/1366179

Comment: Anyway, being more realistic, I don't suggest arguing directly. Simply email with "yes I can do that, here are the likely consequences, please confirm you wish me  to continue". Copy in more than one person so they can't just delete it. You can mix some positive _and_ negative consequences in there, so it doesn't look like a complaint. (If there aren't any positive consequences at all, then maybe invent some inconsequential ones which won't matter if they never happen.) Then you never actually said "no"...you just made sure they can't claim they didn't know what would happen :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your location of your workspace to server. Here are the steps:

1.Team->Team Project Collection Settings->Source Control...->Workspace Settings Tab

Change the default workspace type from "Local (recommended)" to "Server".[image]
2.Source Control Explorer->Workspace Combobox->Workspaces...->Edit...->Advanced->Location Please let other users change the location from "Local" to "Server".
[image]